# How to horizontally align pseudo element with element and its container

Tags: html, css, frontend

I've been through some CSS practice lately. Let's say I have the following HTML/CSS code of a calendar web app you can see in my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/akimo13/pen/XWmoKWN). 
What I need is to have the ".day_body" element and the "+" pseudo element along with its white circle container horizontally aligned. Furthermore, I need that "+" to fit in the centre of the white circle. Unfortunately editing the HTML or using flexbox is not an option for now.
Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

```
<div class="calendar_plan">
 <div class="day_title">Today</div>
 <div class="day_body">19 May 2020</div>
 <div class="day_add">
  <span class="plus_sign"></span>
 </div>
<div>

.calendar_plan {
  background-color: teal;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.day_title {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.day_body {
  font-size: 2em;
  float: left;
}
.day_add {
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.day_add:after {
  display: block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  content: "\002B";
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #999;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 4rem;
}
.day_add:hover:after {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Add `text-align: center;` to `.day-add` to align the plus within the circle. Why can't you use flexbox? And what exactly should be aligned horizontally? The bottom of the circle with the button of the body? Or the mid of the body with the mid of the circle? Or top and top?

Comment: That worked smoothly, thanks! Well, it's a part of a class and flexbox hasn't been taught yet. Actually the date "19 May 2020" should be aligned with the centre of the circle and the + symbol. Like if the horizontal line of + could extend it would strike through the date.

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned in the comment, adding `text-align: center;` to `.day-add` helps to align the plus sign.

To horizontally align the the date with the circle, you could increase the line-height of the `.day_body` to the half of the line-height of the circle (`4em`): `line-height: 2em;`. Nevertheless this moves the date a little bit 'down'. Is that fine?

Alternatively you could use absolute positioning of the circle.

```css
.calendar_plan {
  background-color: teal;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.day_title {
  font-size: 2.2em;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.day_body {
  font-size: 2em;
  float: left;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.day_add {
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.day_add:after {
  display: block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  content: "\002B";
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #999;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.day_add:hover:after {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar_plan">
  <div class="day_title">Today</div>
  <div class="day_body">19 May 2020</div>
  <div class="day_add">
    <span class="plus_sign"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: I  had added a negative margin-top on .day_add:after and it worked, I like your solution much better though. It works for me. Thanks!